# Why custom converter is not picked up with spring boot and kotlin?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

My controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
class TestController() {
    @PostMapping("/url")
    fun createNewApartmentAd(@RequestBody createAdRequest: CreateAdRequest) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Data class:

```
data class CreateAdRequest(
    val title: String,
    val images: List<AdImage> = emptyList()
)

data class AdImage(
    val type: String,
    val image: ByteArray
)
```

Converter:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import java.util.*

@Component
class AdImageConverter: Converter<String, AdImage> {
    override fun convert(source: String): AdImage {
             //Code
    }
}
```

All the time when i send string inside json and want it to became AdImage, I am getting this error:

> "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `x.y.z.c.v.z.AdImage` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value

I verified that converter is pickup by component scan and bean it is created out of it.

Comment: I don't think Spring's `Converter` classes are used during JSON deserialization. If you need a custom `String` to `AdImage` JSON deserialization, you need to implement Jackson's `JsonDeserializer`. See the duplicate for more info.

Comment: @g00glen00b saw this earlier, it does not work for me. Getting
problem: Not found 
```problem: Not found type<EOL> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 9] ```